# Docusaurus - Infima Card Animation

Tags: reactjs, jsx, docusaurus

Would appreciate some help, I have been working with docusaurus and Infima (built in ui framework). I would like to make my cards as links to either external or internal (ie within Docusaurus) file and have an animated border affect much like Miscrosoft Deisgn Sytem (animated border and removal of shadow). I have acheived removal of border yay. I have tried a number of things that have not worked....ie targeting the border, wrapping it in a Link or a....then styling that.

https://fluent2.microsoft.design/

```
          <div className="card">
        <div className="card__head">This is the heading</div>
        <div className="card__body">
          some content about the main feature
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Code that I am referring to is at line 41

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sleepy-resonance-gung28

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the time to read up on how to make a [mre], also reading [ask] can help.

Comment: not new but thank you, just wanting some help